# what does "number one guy on a number two job" mean

Tags: expressions

I just heard today someone saying "I was a number one guy on a number two job". I did not get what that means exactly.

Comment: It makes me think of a second string quarterback (referencing American Football).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further context, I would assume it means that he was the person in charge of an unpleasant task—a pun on the use of "number two" as a common slang term for defecation (in other words, it was a shitty job).

Comment: Yeah, that person was indeed speaking about cleaning toilets, but I did not get him then, now I do. Thank you.

Comment: That would be ***defecation***, not *defection*

Answer (score 1):

The number one guy is a **misutilized** resource.